# Eclipse Plugin for Full Remote Development

Tags: eclipse

Are there any Eclipse plugin allowing a full remote development (including using git installed on the remote machine) as the "Remote Development" extension does for VS Code ?

Answer (score 0):

Git is implicitly designed to work with remote git repositories, but it still does require a local git repository and git toolset.  You can use the "eGit" plugin set already installed in Eclipse to "clone" from remote git repositories to your desktop.  You don't need additional plugins for this.

Comment: With VS Code we can use remote git as local repository without having any git installed on local machine. Unfortunately, eGit cannot do the same thing without a local one.